# OpenGL VBO program gives blank screen

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I've been trying to convert some of my code to modern OpenGL. I've gotten it to the point where I don't get any OpenGL errors, but nothing shows up when I try to draw an object. Here's my code (minus context creation, and error checking):

```
//Compile shaders and create/link program
//I very highly doubt the problem's here (all my tests say it worked fine),
//so I'm leaving this out for now,  but I'll dig it out of my classes if
//there's no obvious problem with the VBO code.

//Create VAO, VBO

unsigned vaoId, vboId;
int positionAttributeLocation;
float vertices[] = {...vertex data here...};
unsigned indices[] = {...index data here...};

positionAttributeLocation = glGetAttribLocation(programId, "position");

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoId);
glGenBuffers(1, &vboId);

glBindVertexArray(vaoId);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, null);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);

//Create index buffer
unsigned indexId;
glGenBuffers(1, &indexId);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexId);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glUseProgram(programId);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(indices)/sizeof(unsigned int), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, null);
```

Not quite SSCCE, but I think that's all the code that could possibly be causing an issue and it's pretty much self-contained.

Comment: have you tried drawing it w/o VBOs first? If that works then you may want to ensure that your GPU supports VBOs. You can check this with the GLGetInfo function (I can't remember what it's called exactly...)

Comment: My code worked when I was using the fixed-function pipeline, but I've gutted most of that and replaced it with shader/VBO code. I'm using OpenGL 3.3, so I'm forced to use VBOs. I'm sure my GPU supports them because its drivers go up to OpenGL 4.2 and VBOs became core long before that.

Comment: 3.3 doesn't force you to use shaders. Compatibility profile allows you to use FFP.

Comment: That's true, but I'm not sure how to set that up with SDL, and the bindings I'm using don't include any of the deprecated OpenGL functions. I might just post the VBO code snippets unless someone can find something obviously wrong with my steps.

Comment: I'd just put up the code, there's just too much potential for misunderstanding or subtle mistakes in trying to guess from your translation. Looking at real code there is no ambiguity over what you're doing.

Comment: I decided to try it without VBOs as suggested. I've added the details to the original post. I'm not sure if the problems there are caused by lack of a compatibility context; I'm not sure if that's automatically created by supporting drivers or if I have to request it through SDL somehow.
*Edit: *
Actually, scratch that about the compatibility context; I've actually got it set to use OpenGL 2.1, so now I'm _really_ stumped as to why this doesn't work.

Comment: If you want some help, you need to post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) code. Not vague description of what your code is like, not 2 or 3 lines, but enough code that will reproduce the problem. Without it we are just wasting our time by guessing.

Comment: My program started giving me an access violation instead of just refusing to draw. I'm not sure if it's something I did to the code or just the new hardware I started using. It might very well be a problem with the element array.

Comment: I'm also busy working on this exact problem. From googling, as far as I can tell, you shouldn't be using gltranslate, etc, if using opengl 3.x (and up?). *Maybe* our problem lies with the data just not being rendered on screen? Not an answer I know, but mebbe a kick in the right direction???

Comment: Ok, confirmed the above. The problem with me, and my render func looks a lot like yours, was with the cg program, and the 'ModelViewProj' variable. Add "cgGLSetStateMatrixParameter(modelViewMatrix, CG_GL_MODELVIEW_PROJECTION_MATRIX, CG_GL_MATRIX_IDENTITY);" to your prog just before gldrawarrays and in your cg file add "OUT.HPos = mul(ModelViewProj, IN.position);". Google these to find out more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. With some of my refactoring, I forgot to set my width and height variables properly, creating a 0 by 0 viewport. Oops...

Answer (score 0):

Try `glUseProgram()` before your `glGetAttribLocation()/glEnableVertexAttribArray()` calls.

Comment: I've actually got it before glEnableVertexAttribArray() (I had to refactor some code to make the example concise), but not before glGetAttribLocation(). I doubt that it will affect the latter, but I'll try. Incidentally, is glGetAttribLocation() the right call to use for GLSL's new in/out variables?

Comment: I've tried an OpenGL debugger and it looks like all the VBO stuff is going through. I'll poke around and see if I can find anything else that could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem more than likely lies with your cg program and modelview space.

Add `cgGLSetStateMatrixParameter(modelViewMatrix, CG_GL_MODELVIEW_PROJECTION_MATRIX, CG_GL_MATRIX_IDENTITY);` to your program just before gldrawarrays, and in your cg file add `OUT.HPos = mul(ModelViewProj, IN.position);`.

Also add `modelViewMatrix` as a cgparameter in you initcg section.

I worked this out from the basic opengl samples in the cgtoolkit, and my render function is very similar to yours and now works after having the same problem.